# Questions I've asked should be (optionally) highlighted as interesting even if none of the tags are interesting

Tags: feature-request, questions, user-interface, tag-watching

I think it'd be beneficial if there was at least the option to consider all questions I've asked to be "interesting" (highlighted as if there was an interesting tag) regardless of whether or not the question is tagged with one of my interesting tags.  I could understand some people not necessarily wanting it on by default, so I'm not sure what the default would be for this option if it existed but I definitely think it could be a useful option to give.

To me it just makes inherent sense that your own question is considered *interesting*, after all you wouldn't have asked it otherwise.  So for that reason, highlighting it as such would serve the same purpose as highlighting questions with tags that you consider interesting **except** you are less likely to be looking for your own question with the intent of answering it like you would others' questions.

The one *specific* example that drove this was I posted a question and was interested in seeing where it sat on the "Active" and "Unanswered" queues since I know that once it falls down past a certain point it's less likely to be happened upon unless it's got interesting enough tags and/or search keywords so that people can find it.

*edit*:  added clarification paragraphs

Comment: **making everything have a higher "emphasis" just makes everything turn into noise**

Comment: If you think it would be beneficial, you should explain why.

Comment: Oh wait. Your title doesn't match the body. **Self Posts** should be highlighted in my opinion, including questions you give answers to. This is assuming that Jeff doesn't plan on implementing some kinda custom notification settings for "subscribing" to the questions that you give an answer on

Comment: To clarify for @Earlz - **Self posts** to me meant **questions I asked**.  If there's a better concise term, let me know.  I guess just "My own questions" would have worked but then it didn't sound like a general concept to put as a feature request.

Comment: Try "Self-authored posts"

Comment: @ccornet That's a good suggestion, edited.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that the main benefit of the "interesting" highlighting would be to make it easier to discover content you'd be interested in. When you asked a question, you should already be very aware of it's existence and there really is no need to additionally try to get your attention for that question.

If anything, it would make much more sense to have a completely new and different highlighting for your own questions and answers.

Comment: The only potential downside to that is that it's a little more visual noise and then it potentially opens the door for "well now I want another classification with a different color" which could be a slippery slope.  I do think this is a good suggestion though.